# addFromString(): Invalid or uninitialized for ziparchive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have a problem when I try to create a zip archive.
I have this error:

> Warning: ZipArchive::addFromString(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

the code

```
$Zip = new \ZipArchive();
$intent_file = 'dialogflow_api' . '-' . date('YmdHis') . '.zip';
$result = $Zip->open($transfer_directory . $intent_file, $Zip->CREATE);

if ($result) {
    foreach ($apps as $data) {
        $file = $data['products_name'];
        $json_structure .= '
            "supportedLanguages": [
                "' . $language_code . '"
            ]
        ';

        $json_structure .='}'

        $Zip->addFromString('intents/' . $file . '_' . $language_code . '.json', $json_structure);
    }

    $Zip->close();
} else {
    error_log('OM\Zip::open() ' . $transfer_directory . $intent_file . ' file error: ' . $Zip->message($result));
}
```

Comment: Please show how you initialized `$Zip` and your call to `$Zip->open(...)`.

Comment: @Jeto Code updated - Tk

Comment: Don't manually create json strings. Use `json_encode()` instead.

Comment: `$Zip->CREATE` should be `\ZipArchive::CREATE` (not sure this is causing the issue though, so just posting it as a comment for now).